Given a standard normal r.v. $ X $, how can I compute the transformation $ Y = \sqrt{|X|} $?
I am working through a problem which seems closely related to the Chi-square distribution, however keep getting stuck on the computation and intuition behind the task.
So far, I have expressed the transformation from $ Y = \sqrt{|X|} $ to $ |X| = Y^2 $, and noted that the relation $x = y^2$ is clearly not bijective and therefore we must utilise the CDF rather than an inverse transformation between $X$ and $Y$.
In attempting to find $\mathbf{F}_Y (y)$, I have determined: $\mathbf{F}_Y (y) = \mathbf{P} (\sqrt{|x|} \leq y) = \mathbf{P} (|x| \leq y^2)$.
From here, I feel a confusion with the absolute value sign of x. I believe I am able to claim $ \mathbf{P} (|x| \leq y^2) = \mathbf{P}( -y^2 \leq x \leq y^2)$, and lastly state that $\mathbf{F}_Y (y) = \phi(y^2) - \phi(-y^2)$, where $\phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal r.v., and by symmetry of the normal distribution we can then write $\mathbf{F}_Y (y) = 2\phi(y^2) - 1$.
I believe now I would need to differentiate $\mathbf{F}_Y (y)$, however these seems extremely computationally heavy and confusing and I wonder if there is a more seamless choice of actions which might lead to fewer arithmetic errors too. Is there something relating to the Jacobian that must be used? It hasn't been brought up in any of my lectures, however my books reference it a fair bit.
In my textbook, in transforming $ Y = X^2$ instead, the final function determined reads: $f _Y (y) = 2\varphi(\sqrt{y}) \cdot \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \varphi(\sqrt{y})y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.
Would it be fair to say by some level of symmetry that for my case, $f _Y (y) = \varphi(y^2)y^{-2}$? I also would like to know what $\varphi$ actually represents. I hadn't heard of varphi until I started typing in this question with LaTeX. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

For the record, it's $\lvert X\rvert=Y^2$, not $X=Y^2$. Differentiating $2\phi(y^2)-1$ (or even $\phi(y^2)-\phi(-y^2)$, for that matter) is trivial.


When you say you expect differentiating $2\phi(y^2) - 1$ to be "computationally heavy", is it the $\phi(\cdot)$ you're referring to, the $y^2$, or both? 2) Are you concerned that the pdf for $Y=X^2$ looks a bit off from your pdf for something like $X=Y^2$?


And I promise I'm not trying to be obnoxious, but I'd be slightly annoyed if I were so close and someone just gave me the answer :). But to address your last question, I think it's correct to call $\varphi$ a lowercase $\phi$.

I'm not even sure what the (⋅) function is to compute it, but if I take the CDF as it is and differentiate for the PDF, I would have to first take the integral from -inf to t, or in our case, 0 to y^2. I tried computing the integral with Wolfram but it returned an error function so I think my thinking is way off. I hope this all makes sense, I'm still trying to learn how to describe what's going on

It all makes perfect sense, you're just doing way too much work :). If you don't sort it out after this, I'll fill in the gaps -- just add an @dmk when you respond, so that I know -- but for now: You mention the cdf "as it is". Well, what is it? How would you describe what it's the cdf of? And so if you differentiate it, what is that the pdf of? (And if you answer these questions, can you avoid taking an integral?)

You were on the right track with $F_Y(y) = 2\Phi(y^2)-1$. Then, differentiating this expression leads to $f_Y(y) = 4y\phi(y^2)$, where $\phi(x) = \Phi'(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ being the standard gaussian.
